# how to draw LFT?

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, complex-integration, linear-fractional-transformation

[image]

How to draw this dark area to $w=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$
so difficult to draw LFT...

Comment: Start with subjecting the unit circle to $w$. I mean, you got to start somewhere, right? Mobius transformation rings a bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember:

1. LFT's transform straight lines and circles into straight lines an circles.
2. LFT's preserve angles.

The point $1$ goes to $\infty$. This means that the two circles bordering the gray are are transformed in parallel lines (since they touch with the same tangent at $z=1$.) Moreover, these lines must be perpendicular to the image of the real axis, which happens to be the real axis again. The rest should be easy.

Comment: still difficult..... need to practice more but really helpful thank you! :-D